# Postgres: problem with FK contraint

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key-relationship

How can I solve FK contraint? With trigger or something else?

```
#IF "DELETE FROM human where name='a';", error due to the FK contraist.

# If the error, I want in the order:
# FIRSTLY. DELETE FROM address where name='a';
# SECONDLY. DELETE FROM human where name='a';


DROP TABLE human;
DROP TABLE address;

CREATE TABLE human(
        name varchar(300) PRIMARY KEY not null

);

CREATE TABLE address(
        name varchar(300)
                references human.name

);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE address (
    name varchar(300) REFERENCES human (name) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

[Chapter 5.3.5. Foreign Keys](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) of the fine manual would be very helful.